# Get latest date with criterias in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am trying to get the latest date of multiple criterias back.

Here is what I tried:

[image]

```
=MAX(IF(AND(A2=$A$2:$A$16;B2=$B$2:$B$16);$C$2:$C$16;""))
```

What I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: @user3964075 I tried this and the result I get back is: `#VALUE!` in all result cells.

Comment: I didn't notice the second problem with `AND` function pointed in the answer, that's why I removed my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're almost right but there are two issues with your formulation:

(1) These are Array Formulas - not sure if you were aware of that. An array formula takes an operation over multiple cells, when a single cell would otherwise be expected. Excel can do this if you confirm the fomrula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just enter. This will result in an array of results, one result for each cell operated on. To get a final answer, you need to collapse that array into a single number. It looks like you are aware of this, hence your wrapping of everything in the MAX function.

(2) When using Array formulas, be careful of AND / OR, as those functions naturally take an array of responses (TRUE;FALSE;FALSE etc) and collapse them into a single answer. In your case, as written your AND statements would collapse all tests into a single TRUE, and then it would try to give a value from column C but wouldn't properly recognize that you actually want 1 result from column C for each row that was TRUE.

So instead, you need to approach multiple criteria differently. One way is to use the natural TRUE/FALSE argument of an if statement. Together, this formula will look like this in K2 (and dragged down):

```
=MAX(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$16;IF(B2=$B$2:$B$16;$C$2:$C$16;"")))
```

Remember to confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Thanks. However, I have never used ArrayFormulas before. I inputed the formula in K and dragged it down. Then selected from K2 to K16 and put the cursor in the formula field. Then I pressed: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. However I get the same value, the first value in every cell... Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Enter it in 1 cell initially. Within that cell, instead of pressing TAB / ENTER to leave the cell, press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. If you did this right, it should show {}'s around the whole thing (you do not enter the {}s yourself). Then after you have done that properly for the first cell, copy the formula to the cells below.

Comment: Nice explanation of AND/OR, whose non-use in array formulas is not widely understood.